# move_uploaded_file file does not exist?

Tags: php, linux

Quick question I am trying to move an uploaded file to a directory outside of the root to /opt/ffencoderd/data/media and I get file does not exist. If I use exec() in the same file to execute clamscan in /usr/bin/clamscan it works. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], '/opt/ffencoderd/data/media'.'/'.$id2)
or die ("Couldn't upload ".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']."\n");
```

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(opt/ffencoderd/data/media/fa3eeb1d502ec3cb7221cac889a8922a)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed
>   to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site/progressbar/upload.php
>   on line 99
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file()
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable
>   to move '/tmp/phpRh2VMZ' to
>   'opt/ffencoderd/data/media/fa3eeb1d502ec3cb7221cac889a8922a'
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site/progressbar/upload.php
>   on line 99

Comment: No one knows, since you did not provide any details. How `exec()` is related to `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: It is in the same file and it can access a directory outside of root using /directory. That is why I thought it was relevant. Both files exist yet using move_uploaded_file does not say it does.

Comment: :-S I think that some code would help.

Comment: I see leading `/` in the code but don't see it in the warning. Are you sure the warning is for exactly that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test that the directory exists and that your PHP script has permissions to write to it with:

```
echo is_writable('/opt/ffencoderd/data/media');
```

If it returns false it may be that the directory doesn't exist. If you know the directory exists then you will need to modify permissions on the directory. If it has the correct permissions then you'll need to check your [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) and [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.path-directory) settings.

Comment: If he hadn't permissions or violated open_basedir restrictions - he would get another errors.

Comment: @zerkms: That's right. I included the fact that it may not exist but I had added additional information before he posted the exact error messages.

Comment: thanks for your help guys +1 to all helpers comments, the directory just didn't exist lol and needed permissions changed...I did learn from this though from you guys in troubleshooting this issue.